# OpenCV-Android demo crashes

Tags: android, opencv

I want to develop an picture recognition app for Android with OpenCV-Android 2.4.2.

I'm using Android 4.0.4 on my phone (LG P500 "Optimus One"), but the demo-application crashes without an error. It only leaves an black screen...

What ist the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you faced [this bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1244). It will be fixed in [2.5.0 release](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues?query_id=21).

You can wait for official fix or use unofficial fix of this problem - see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/-Gr-cZpeB3s). It helped me (my device is Motorola Defy).

Comment: maybe, but i think it's the ARM v6 processor, which has problems with floats, like in minecraft PE...